# Change a string by task name in gulp

Tags: javascript, replace, pipe, gulp

Is it possible that when I run 'gulp INPUT', so that the input will get any value, that value will change 'myText' to INPUT value ?

```
gulp.task(INPUT, function() {
    gulp.src(['file.js'])
        .pipe(replace('myText', INPUT)
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./file.js));
});
```

Comment: Taks names are strings. I don't think understand your question completely but it seems implausible.

Comment: I've got a JSON file that needs a version to be changed
"version": "1.1.1", so if it is any possible way to change the version from Gulp, so I can change to 1.1.2 , and possibly at any time I decide to change to 1.1.3

Comment: if you want to just change the version or get the version there are other gulp plugins which do that

Comment: I tried gulp-tag-version, but something is wrong with it.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32005849/gulp-tag-version-running-command