# gulp-tag-version running command?

Tags: javascript, task, gulp

I installed gulp-tag-version, but when I am running the command 'gulp tag v1.1.1', it will not confirm this as a task

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var tag_version = require('gulp-tag-version');  

gulp.task('tag', function() {
  return gulp.src(['./package.json']).pipe(tag_version());
});
```

So what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it has been added correct. The command however would be:

```
gulp tag
```

Which would look at the version in your package.json file and tag the last commit with it.

Refer to this example for more advanced features:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-tag-version#advanced-example-gulpfile-with-bumping-and-commiting

Comment: But can't I change the version in the package.json with this plug-in. I though that this plug-in would have this function.

Comment: In the example I linked to it enables you to increment the tagged version numbers. To do this you will need to implement as specified in the example and then use the following commands.


 *     gulp patch     # makes v0.1.0 → v0.1.1
 *     gulp feature   # makes v0.1.1 → v0.2.0
 *     gulp release   # makes v0.2.1 → v1.0.0

Comment: Thank you, Now I understand that documentation.